# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am newbie to spring framework. I am trying to work on **Maven**. I just want to open an index page when the project is run but was unable to do it

Error says **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter** 
[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHgJe.png)

**pom.xml** of parent

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nishan</groupId>
            <artifactId>LifeStyle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**web.xml** of WebModule

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nishan.webmodule"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

servlet page to navigate to index page

```
   @Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class DefaultServlet {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Find the JAR that contains that class and add it to your Maven pom.xml.  If you find that Maven does include that JAR, check your packaging to see if that JAR appears in the package at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for the `<dependencyManagement>` element (emphasis mine):

"Default dependency information for projects that inherit fromthis one. **The dependencies in this section are not immediately resolved**. Instead, when a POM derived from this one declares a dependency described by a matching groupId and artifactId, the version and other values from this section are used for that dependency if they were not already specified."

In other words, you are probably lacking the proper `<dependency>` definition in the module POM.